# How can i change cross origin blocked in angular

Tags: angularjs, http, cors

**I'm trying to fetch data from api in angular $http but i got an Error Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://****/api/**/**/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. below is my code file **
**app.js**

```
 var myApp = angular.module('abc',['ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate']);
```

**controller.js**

```js
myApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});

myApp.controller('careersCtrl', ['$scope','$http','dataService', function($scope,$http,dataService){
 $scope.testVar = "hello";

    dataService.dataSearch().then(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.data = dataResponse;
            console.log('hello');
    });
 
}]);




myApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    this.dataSearch = function() {
        return $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'http://*****.cc/api/****/****/',
            headers:{
                'Authorization': 'Token token=61d1802e-d539-4fe7-8110-1651053e6e0b'
            }
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: What backend are you using? This is something that must be fixed on your server

Answer (score 0):

It's not blocked by angular, what you need is to enable CORS
The best methods are described here:

http://enable-cors.org